# Parameters sent by the same value every time

Tags: c#

I was working on a Login form and after I finished it, I found a silly problem!

I entered a wrong password and after I had corrected it I received "WRONG PASSWORD" again!

```
string username = txt_Username.Text.Trim().ToLower();
string password = txt_Password.Text.Trim();

db.cmd.CommandText = "select count(id) from Users where [username]=@un and [password]=@pw";
db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", username);
db.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", db._md5(password));
```

I thought it is because every time cmd wants to be executed, @un and @pw got the previous values and because of that I changed my codes to test my idea:

```
db.cmd.CommandText = "select count(id) from Users where [username]='"+username+"' and [password]='"+password+"'";
```

It still has the same result!
I deleted the codes witch opens the new form after entering the correct password so now when you enter wrong password after entering correct password, it will say you're password is correct :))

Also db class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace My_Images
    {
        class Database
        {
        private string connection_string = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=!@~dbpw~@!;";
        public OleDbConnection cn;
        public OleDbCommand cmd;

        public bool connection_error = false;
        public string connection_error_reason;

        public string _md5(string txt)
        {
            byte[] A = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt);
            byte[] H = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(A);

            return BitConverter.ToString(H).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }

        public Database()
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new OleDbConnection(connection_string);
                cn.Open();

                connection_error = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                connection_error = true;
                connection_error_reason = e.Message;
            }

            if (connection_error == false)
            {
                cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're using `AddWithValue` extensively, it's worth being aware of [the pitfalls of doing so](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @C4ud3x How to fix this.

Comment: @Liam Yes I want. But it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: What is `db` and `db.cmd` ?

Comment: I have forgot to show that codes. I will Edit my post ...

Comment: @Liam The second code doesn't work neither.

Comment: use a debugger and step through the code, check the values for `password` , `_md5(password)` and compare them to the values stored in the database

Comment: @derpirscher I did. Password in the database and _md5(password) has the same value!

Comment: so, how do you execute the query, how do you interpret the result? how do you generate your message `WRONG PASSWORD`?

Comment: @derpirscher Good Question!

Comment: @derpirscher if (Convert.ToInt16(db.cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) <= 0)
                {
                    // Wrong
                }

Comment: @mohsennemati have you tried executing the query directly in the database system (take exactly the same values, as they are used in `AddWithValue`!) ? do you experience any exceptions? what is the result of `ExecuteScalar()`. Check it in the debugger. Maybe its an issue with the DB-Collation. In gereral, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now I see it, you only create new `SqlCommand cmd` directly after you open the connection. If the first attempt goes wrong you are reusing the same command object. And when you execute the same command twice (just changing the `CommandText` does not make it a new command) you use `AddWithValue`. But this way you are just appending your values to the existing `cmd.Parameters` collection and not replacing the existing values. You have to do a

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

before adding the new values. Otherwise SQL server will always use the first two parameters provided, which are, indeed the ones, you entered the first time and obviously the wrong ones.

Answer (score 1):

first of all check value of textbox "txt_Password"

you can Add parameters to cmd like..

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", db._md5(password));
```

Comment: he does in the first query. the second one is only a test

Comment: ya i had write it only for first one

Comment: @derpirscher It is not a good place to ask this question but why people give negative to my question?

Comment: @mohsennemati your question is not written very good. relevant parts (for instance query execution, or db schema) are missing. Your two examples do different things for the same problem, ...

Comment: @derpirscher Yes! Thanks.